# Hibernate Mapping Could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to get a List of my entity class from the Postgres DB using Hibernate. Seems like everything is correct in the configuration and all the hibernate properties looks good for me.

When i invoke to the findAll method i get a org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

This are my files:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/EES_Settings</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- C3P0 connection pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">20</property>

        <!--  Connection testing settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.automaticTestTable">conTestTable</property>

        <mapping class="com.deere.isg.easyequipmentsetup.easyequipmentsetup.entities.Configuration" resource="Mappers/Configuration.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

```
@Id
@Column(name = "guid")
private String guid;

@Column(name = "profile_name")
private String profileName;

@Column(name= "machine_id")
private String machineId;

@Column(name= "implement_id")
private String implementId;

@Column(name= "creation_date")
@Type(type="timestamp")
private Timestamp creationDate;

@Column(name= "modification_date")
@Type(type="timestamp")
private Timestamp modificationDate;
```

```
List<Configuration> configurations = (List<Configuration>) getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select Cast(guid as varchar) guid, profile_name, machine_id, implement_id, creation_data, modification_date from ees_configuration").list();
```

The expected result is the collection with the records from DB, the actual result is the mentioned exception.

Comment: Always share the complete stactrace

Comment: Why you are using native SQL and not HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Criteria and method list to retrieve all records stored for the entity:

```
List<Configuration> configurations = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Configuration.class).list();
```

It's not recommend to use sql query if you use the ORM(Hibernate in your case).

In alternative if your prefer to use Sql query and extract only some columns of bean, use `addScalar` to bind all column with type you need

Comment: Do not answer with `Try to do this:`. explain what you have done and why